# Validating custom data types with IDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, inotifypropertychanged, idataerrorinfo

I have a model for an object holding data, which is bound to an input form. This model uses `IDataErrorInfo` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` to validate its contents. I have a method for converting a string like `"(6*20+sin(20))"` into a `double` value. The text box for entering this text is bound to `Mass.TextValue`. However when this value changes, it does not call the `OnPropertyChanged()` method as seen below, and so the value is not validated, how can I get around this issue?

```
    private DynamicDouble mass = new DynamicDouble("Mass", 1);
    public DynamicDouble Mass
    {
        get { return mass; }
        set { mass = value; OnPropertyChanged("Mass");  }
    }
```

The `DynamicDouble` class also uses `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IDataErrorInfo` as well and the validation inside is called but it is the validation for converting the `string` into a `double` value, not for checking whether that value is greater than 0 (in case of the mass). I cannot put that range check in the `DynamicDouble` class as it is used for more than just the `Mass` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting all of the required validation logic into the ViewModel class and adding properties to it that pointed to values in the model itself and validating that input instead of doing the validation lower down.

Answer (score 0):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to say for sure what the issue is.

However, based on what little information is here, it *seems* as though there is no reason for the `OnPropertyChanged()` method to be called, because the `Mass` setter method is never called. If the only thing that is bound is `Mass.TextValue`, then the only thing that will change is the `TextValue` property, and not the `Mass` property.

If you want to do validation that is not appropriate in the `DynamicDouble` class itself, then you should write a [`ValidationRule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule(v=vs.110).aspx) object and attach that to the binding that uses the `TextValue` property as the source.

Alternatively, your model object should not expose the `Mass` object directly, but rather should implement e.g. `MassTextValue` and delegate to the `DynamicDouble.TextValue` property, performing additional validation as needed (and of course, forwarding validation results from `DynamicDouble` also as needed).